Missing i915 firmware during initramfs update for kernel 6.8.11-amd64
┌──(professorxlevel10㉿KALI)-[~]
└─$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k 6.8.11-amd64 
[sudo] password for professorxlevel10: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_gsc_1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_guc_70.bin for module i915

I tried to recreate the initramfs for my specific kernel because this is the kernel that all my other modules set on when my Kali Linux initially boots up. I have a dual boot set-up on my laptop with Windows 11 and Kali Linux. I gladly accept any suggestions if there is a way around this for an easy fix. I can boot into advanced Kali Linux safe mode, which allows me to get to the terminal to run commands.

Is the missing firmware causing you actual problems, or are you only interested in avoiding the warnings?

I believe the missing firmware might be my actual problem, I cannot upload my kernel 6.8.11 amd64  I keep getting the following error,  (end kernel panic - not syncing), get (this) I found the missing firmware for i915 however I was able to download all the missing firmware, but I can't install it,  I'm getting an error when trying to install it through the terminal command line.   This has been quite a challenge, in resolving this technical issue.

Because you are seeing the error message, I would conclude the missing firmware is not the cause of your troubles. Those firmware files are all related to Intel iGPU display driver, and since your display works without them, the firmware is apparently not essential. The "kernel panic-not syncing" message at boot usually means the system is not able to access the root filesystem, probably because the initramfs is missing a driver for a) disk controller b) the filesystem type for your root filesystem, or c) some necessary infrastructure to access the root filesystem.

The guc firmware for Intel iGPUs has to do with things like power management, the huc firmware provides accelerated video decoding functions. The mtl refers to the Meteor Lake processors: if your system does not have a Intel Core Ultra Series 1 mobile processor, then the missing firmware is not at all relevant to your system, and your problem is elsewhere.
